# TF get the time of last transform

Tags: ros, tf2-ros, timestamp, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!
I want to check if the tf2_ros::Buffer received a valid transform from A to B in the last x seconds (to throw an error in case of time out). So something like `buffer.canTransform(A, B, ros::Time(0))` with an additional argument for how far in the past the transform can be.

Is there a way to get the timestamp of the last available transform so that I can compare it to the current time?
This sounds like a pretty common use case to me, but I could not find anything suitable.

Thanks a lot!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/413199/tf-get-the-time-of-last-transform/) by [labude](https://answers.ros.org/users/103641/labude/) on ROS Answers with karma: 98 on 2023-03-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To achieve your query, you can do a `lookupTransform` and then check the resultant (latest) transform's timestamp is in your query window.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2023-03-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [labude](https://answers.ros.org/users/103641/labude/) on 2023-03-11**:
That's a good idea, thanks.